# Is it correct to say "ice creams were considered to be a special meal" or "ice creams were considered to have been a special meal"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-choice

Which one is grammatically correct, *were considered to be* or *were considered to have been*?

> Ice creams were considered to be a special meal.

Comment: It depends on the larger context of the tenses involved. Both could be correct in different situations.

Comment: Probably the first, but only because I can't imagine a context where the second is preferable to the first

Comment: The first means that, at some time in the past, people thought "Ice creams are a special meal". The second means that, at that time, they thought "Ice creams _used to be_ a special meal".

Comment: Many people would not describe an ice cream as a 'meal'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I was deliberately ignoring the oddness of the sentence. Chilambe, it would be more natural to say _a special treat_ or _a dessert for special occasions_.

Comment: Also "ice *creams*" sounds very strange.  When we're talking about it in general, we would say "ice *cream*", singular, because we're talking about it like a mass noun.

Comment: Thanks for the responses ... Well noted